# Usando array javascript dentro $("tr:contains('"+array+"')")

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho 3 funções, para fazer o filtro de intervalo de datas num intervalo de 2.

É assim, eu tenho uma data de inicio e outra de fim, e dentro dessas duas datas ele procura numa table dentro de suas trs e tds as tais datas que estarão nesse intervalo.

As funções usadas para fazer esse intervalo (que é gurdado num array):

```
// prototype of dates
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf())
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
    return dat;
}

//GET DATES INTERVAL FUNCTION
function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
    var dateArray = new Array();
    var currentDate = startDate;
    while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        dateArray.push( new Date (currentDate) )
        currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
    }
    return dateArray;
}
```

E aqui onde ocorre o change que disparada essas funções e dentro dela eu quero que procure esse intervalo de datas que eu preciso:

```
$("#start").keydown(function(event) {

        var d1 = new Date($(this).val());
        var d2 = new Date($("#end").val());

        console.log(getDates(d1,d2));
    });

    $("#end").keydown(function(event) {

        var d1 = new Date($("#start").val());
        var d2 = new Date($(this).val());

        console.log(getDates(d1,d2));
    });
```

Comment: Qual é sua pergunta?

Comment: Já resolvi, obrigado.

Comment: olá @FabioWilliamConceição, pode compartilhar conosco como resolveu? assim no futuro alguém pode se ajudado com sua pergunta.

Comment: Postei a solução

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução:

```
//GET DATES INTERVAL FUNCTION
function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
var dateArray = new Array();

var currentDate = startDate;

while (currentDate <= stopDate) {

  var newDate = currentDate;

  var res = newDate.toString().split('-');

  res = res[0].toString().split(' ');
  res = res[2] + '/' + monthToNumber(res[1]) + '/' + res[3];

  dateArray.push( res );

  currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);

}

return dateArray;
}

$("#start").keydown(function(event) {

    var d1 = new Date($(this).val());


    var d2 = new Date($("#end").val());

    console.log(getDates(d1,d2));

});

$("#end").keydown(function(event) {

    var d1 = new Date($("#start").val());
    var d2 = new Date($(this).val());

    console.log(getDates(d1,d2));

});
```